# Getting error like this "illegal char * at index 0 *.lock" when Start AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am apply 2 -3 solution but they not work for me. when i start AVD for run App getting this error "illegal char * at index 0 *.lock" and cancel popup show. click on cancel then AVD is not start.

Also i delete lock file in avd folder but that file not delete.